# Page navigation in asp.net

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a asp.net web page where i will navigate pages on the click of the "Next" button

Page1 will got to Page 2 and then page 3 and page4

But in a selection of dropdown in page 1 it decides page 2 should go to page 3 or page 4

How can i know where they set this page navigation? if suppose i need to change the navigation order?

Comment: Could you clarify "in a selection of dropdown in page 1 it decides page 2 should go to page 3 or page 4"? What is "it", and who is "they"?

Comment: This is possibly the most vague question I've seen so far. Please edit to clarify. Why would a dropdown decide something, did you tell it to decide or is this unintended behavior?

Comment: also are you using webforms, winforms or mvc?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should consider the ASP.NET Wizard control.

Here are some links that can help you use it:

[4guysfromrolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506090337/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/061406-1.aspx)

[ScottGu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/21/438732.aspx)

In a nutshell, the wizard control allows you to designate a discrete set of steps users need to follow. It allows for logic to programmatically decide what to display to the user based on previous choices

Hope this helps!

Comment: I agree with the proposed solution, but I think the op is asking how to find the source of behavior in an existing solution (i.e. asked to troubleshoot/enhance someone else's work).

Comment: good point. we'll see what the OP says about the context of the question

Answer (score 0):

There is an event handler associated with the dropdown.  Typically the dropdown control is binded to a method declared in the code behind.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTest" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="ddlTest_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

...

```
protected void ddlTest_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // do some stuff here...
}
```

There might also be a client side (JavaScript) event handler associated with the control.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I understand:

Page 1 sets a drop-down value, navigates to Page 2
Page 2 reads the drop-down value from Page 1 and decides to go to Page 3 or 4 based on that

In your postback method on Page 1, you can read the value set in your drop-down and pass it to page 2.  Store that value on page 2, and use it in the postback method of page 2 to decide which next page to navigate to.